I am trying to create a student information code in MATLAB but it is showing error?
% Define the number of students
numStudents = 3;

% Initialize an array of structures
students(numStudents) = struct('Name', 0, 'Age', 0, 'Grade', 0);

% Loop to input student information
for i = 1:numStudents
fprintf('Enter information for student %d:\n', i);

% Get student name`your text`
students(i).Name = input('Enter Name: ', 's');

% Get student age
students(i).Age = input('Enter Age: ');

% Get student grade
students(i).Grade = input('Enter Grade: ', 's');

fprintf('\n'); % New line for better readability`your text`
end

% Display the entered information
fprintf('The entered student information is:\n');
for i = 1:numStudents
fprintf('Student %d:\n', i);
fprintf('Name: %s\n', students(i).Name);
fprintf('Age: %d\n', students(i).Age);
fprintf('Grade: %s\n', students(i).Grade);
fprintf('\n'); % New line for better readability
end

My error is in line 5 saying:

Attempt to call constructor struct with incorrect letter case.
Error in struct (line 5)
students(numStudents) = struct('Name', 0, 'Age', 0, 'Grade', 0);


I am not getting the correct output.

Did you make a file called “struct.m”?

Yes, i have ....

I think, I understood my error it was because of the file name "struct". change the filename and it worked...

Indeed. Never make M-files with the same name as important functions that you want to keep using, as you’ll shadow the function. Also don’t make variables with those names.
